# scala copy objects

Tags: scala, object, copy

Is there a way to make a copy of an object (or even better a list of objects)?
I'm talking about custom objects of classes that may be extended by other classes.

example:

```
class Foo() {
   var test = "test"
}

class Bar() extends Foo {
   var dummy = new CustomClass()
}

var b = new Bar()
var bCopy = b.copy() // or something?
```

Comment: Note that you don't need to make copies if you keep your objects immutable.

Answer (score 26):

In Java, they tried to solve this problem a `clone` method, that works by invoking `clone` in all super-classes, but this is generally considered broken and best avoided, for reasons you can look up (for example [here](http://www.artima.com/intv/bloch13.html)).

So in Scala, as genereally in Java, you will have to make your own copy method for an arbitrary class, which will allow you to specify things like deep vs shallow copying of fields.

If you make you class a `case class`, you get a `copy` method for free. It's actually better than that, because you can update any of the fields at the same time:

```
case class A(n: Int)
val a = A(1)         // a: A = A(1)
val b = a.copy(a.n)  // b: A = A(1) 
val c = a.copy(2)    // c: A = A(2)
```

However inheriting from case classes is deprecated.

Comment: isn't there anything like: Collections.copy(list1, list2) in Java but then for scala?

Comment: @user485659 If you're asking specifically about collections, you can check the documentation and see there are plenty of methods for this kind of thing. `ArrayBuffer` has a `clone` method, for example. But normally you will use immutable `List`, and as Daniel Sobral points out, there is no reason to make a copy.

Comment: @LuigiPlinge How does copy for case classes work? What is it only copy variables by reference, or do something else?