# Design of immutable, typeable, trees

Tags: scala, functional-programming, immutability

Here is a design problem I have faced repeatedly. Suppose you're building a compiler, how do you store the types in the trees?

Consider a simple `Expr` and `Type` hierarchy, and assume that `Plus` and `Equals` are polymorphic (plus on booleans in just `||`, for instance).

```
trait Type
case object BoolType extends Type
case object IntType extends Type
case object Untyped extends Type

trait Expr { var tpe : Type = Untyped }

case class Var(id : String) extends Expr
case class Plus(l : Expr, r : Expr) extends Expr
case class Equals(l : Expr, r : Expr) extends Expr
// ...
```

Assume further that I do not know the type of identifiers when I construct the expression trees, and therefore cannot know the type by construction.
Now a typical typechecking function could look like this:

```
def typeCheck(env : Map[String,Type])(expr : Expr) : Expr = expr match {
  case Var(id) =>
    expr.tpe = env(id)
    expr

  case Plus(l,r) =>
    val tl = typeCheck(env)(l)
    val tr = typeCheck(env)(r)
    assert(tl == tr)
    expr.tpe = tl
    expr

  // etc.
}
```

This is rather straightforward to write, but comes with two major problems:

- `Expr`s are mutable. No one likes mutation.
- Typed and untyped expressions cannot be distinguished. I cannot write a function whose signature specifies that its argument must be a typed expression.

So my question is the following. What is a good way (I dare not say design pattern) to define possibly untyped trees such that:

1. I need to define the `Expr` hierarchy only once.
2. Typed and untyped trees have distinct types and I can choose to make them incompatible.

**Edit:** One more requirement is that it should work for type systems with an unbounded and unpredictable number of types (think: `case class ClassType(classID : String) extends Type`, for instance).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is a perfect use-case for type-level programming!

First, we need a type-level `Option` so that we can represent untyped trees in terms of type-level `None` and typed trees of type `X` in terms of type-level `Some[X]`:

```
// We are restricting our type-level option to
// only (potentially) hold subtypes of `Type`.
sealed trait IsTyped
sealed trait Untyped extends IsTyped
sealed trait Typed[T <: Type] extends IsTyped
```

Next, we lay out our type system hierarchy:

```
sealed trait Type

// We can create complicated subhierarchies if we want.
sealed trait SimpleType extends Type
sealed trait CompoundType extends Type

sealed trait PrimitiveType extends Type
sealed trait UserType extends Type

// Declaring our types.
case object IntType extends SimpleType with PrimitiveType

case object BoolType extends SimpleType with PrimitiveType

// A type with unbounded attributes.
case class ClassType(classId: String) extends CompoundType with UserType

// A type that depends statically on another type.
case class ArrayType(elemType: Type) extends CompoundType with PrimitiveType
```

Now, all that's left is to declare our expression tree:

```
sealed trait Expr[IT <: IsTyped] { val getType: Option[Type] }

// Our actual expression types.
case class Var[IT <: IsTyped](id: String, override val getType: Option[Type] = None) extends Expr[IT]

case class Plus[IT <: IsTyped](l: Expr[IT], r: Expr[IT], override val getType: Option[Type] = None) extends Expr[IT]

case class Equals[IT <: IsTyped](l: Expr[IT], r: Expr[IT], override val getType: Option[Type] = None) extends Expr[IT]

case class ArrayLiteral[IT](elems: List[Expr[_ :< IsTyped]], override val getType: Option[Type] = None) extends Expr[IT]
```

---

**EDIT:**

A simple but complete type-checking function:

```
def typeCheck(expr: Expr[Untyped], env: Map[String, Type]): Option[Expr[Typed[_ :< Type]]] = expr match {
  case Var(id, None) if env isDefinedAt id => Var[Typed[_ <: Type]](id, Some(env(id)))
  case Plus(r, l, None) => for {
      lt <- typeCheck(l, env)
      IntType <- lt.getType
      rt <- typeCheck(r, env)
      IntType <- rt.getType
    } yield Plus[Typed[IntType]](lt, rt, Some(IntType))
  case Equals(r, l, None) => for {
      lt <- typeCheck(l, env)
      lType <- lt.getType
      rt <- typeCheck(r, env)
      rType <- rt.getType
      if rType == lType
    } yield Equals[Typed[BoolType]](lt, rt, Some(BoolType))
  case ArrayLiteral(elems, None) => {
    val elemst: List[Option[Expr[Typed[_ <: Type]]]] =
      elems map { typeCheck(_, env) }
    val elemType: Option[Type] = if (elemst.isEmpty) None else elemst map { elem =>
      elem map { _.getType }
    } reduce { (elemType1, elemType2) =>
      for {
        et1 <- elemType1
        et2 <- elemType2
        if et1 == et2
      } yield et1
    }
    if (elemst forall { _.isDefined }) elemType map { et =>
      ArrayLiteral[Typed[ArrayType]](elemst map { _.get }, ArrayType(et))
    } else None
  }
  case _ => None
}
```

Comment: A usage example would be great. How would you rewrite `typeCheck` in your system?

Comment: This looks like it could be what I was looking for. As Eugene suggests, could you maybe show how you would adapt my `typeCheck` function to your definitions?

Comment: I think you've accidentally confused None and Nothing.  Also, instead of Nothing.type, I think you mean None.

Comment: @Philippe I've provided a typechecking function, along with slightly reworking the system to eliminate some boilerplate.

Answer (score 3):

To make it immutable, you can make up a new Expr instead of changing its contents.  Case classes have a [copy method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8085857/scala-copy-objects) that you can use for just this.

```
trait Type
case object BoolType extends Type
case object IntType extends Type
case object Untyped extends Type

class Expr[A <: Type](tpe : Type = Untyped)

case class Var[A <: Type](id : String, tpe : Type = Untyped) extends Expr[A](tpe)
case class Plus[A <: Type](l : Expr, tpe : Type = Untyped) extends Expr[A](tpe)
case class Equals[A <: Type](l : Expr, tpe : Type = Untyped) extends Expr[A](tpe)
```

Now you're free to do all kinds of nice things like:

```
val x = Var("name")
val y = x.copy(tpe = IntType)
```

However, it is now immutable.  You can solve your problem with figuring out whether it's typed or not by matching against tpe, now that it is one of the arguments for Var, Plus, and Equals.  They also have different types, and their type will change as tpe changes with copy.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. This satisfies the first requirement (everything is immutable), but not the second one (typed and untyped trees have the same --Scala-- type here).

Comment: Ahh, right, I was dealing with the concern that it could be matched against, not that they have distinct types.  For distinct types, you would want to make Typed a trait instead of an object.  I'll resubmit with a solution that satisfies that requirement.

edit: Actually, just realized I don't have a good way of letting you still use copy with mixing in traits.  I'll think about it.

Comment: Actually, adding a parameter to my solution like in @Ptharien's Flame's solution works better than mixins, I think.

Answer (score 1):

This is just an idea.

First if you want to go immutable, obviously you have to get rid of the variable `tpe`.

## Distinct Expression Types

Simply make two hierarchies, one with `TypedExpression <: Expression` and one with `UntypedExpression <: Expression`. This approach will probably result in two nearly identical class hierarchies.

## Make a Type Parameter Signal Typedness

In order to remove the overhead of the two hierarchies (and get some type boilerplate), you could make a single hierarchy and add a type paramater for [a bool type](http://apocalisp.wordpress.com/2010/06/13/type-level-programming-in-scala-part-3-boolean/):

```
sealed trait TBool
sealed trait TTrue extends TBool
sealed trait TFalse extends TBool

trait Expression[T <: TBool]{
  //ensure that this gets only called on typed expressions
  def getType(implicit e: T =:= TTrue): Type
  def typeMe(m: Map[String,Type]): Expression[TTrue] = this.asInstanceOf[Expression[TTrue]]
}
```

I don't really know into how many thousand problems you'll run if you do this. But this is what I would try.